# Grid column to occupy entire screen

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a little project in Xamarin forms and I want the itens in the columns of my grid to space eachother so that they occupy the entire screen. I tried messing with the vertical layout options and it doesn't work (the best so far is using Fill/Fill and expand, but they simply stretch the hell out of the third row so it fills the gap). I'm using VStudio 2019 if that matters.

Also, if u can explain what u did instead of simply writing a code that works, I would be grateful.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.Padding = new Thickness(20);
            var deviceWidht = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
            double buttonWidthandHeight = deviceWidht / 9;
            int buttonCornerRadius = Convert.ToInt32(deviceWidht / 20);

            Grid panel1 = new Grid();
            panel1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            panel1.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });


            Button r1c1 = SetButton(1, 1);
            Button r1c2 = SetButton(1, 2);
            Button r1c3 = SetButton(1, 3);
            Button r2c1 = SetButton(2, 1);
            Button r2c2 = SetButton(2, 2);
            Button r2c3 = SetButton(2, 3);
            Button r3c1 = SetButton(3, 1);
            Button r3c2 = SetButton(3, 2);
            Button r3c3 = SetButton(3, 3);

            Button SetButton (int row, int column)
            {
                Button createdButton = CreateButton(row, column);
                Grid.SetRow(createdButton, row);
                Grid.SetColumn(createdButton, column);
                panel1.Children.Add(createdButton);
                return createdButton;

            }
            Button CreateButton(int row, int column)
            {
                return new Button
                {
                    Text = "Row " + row + " Column " + column,
                    WidthRequest = buttonWidthandHeight,
                    HeightRequest = buttonWidthandHeight,
                    CornerRadius = buttonCornerRadius
                };               
            }

            this.Content = panel1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,you could change the `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` like below:

```
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

The three ColumnDefinition objects both set the Width to 1, meaning that the width of the screen is divided equally beneath the three columns (the same goes for rows).

Second,when you add the button,you should start from the position `0` ,not `1`.

```
Button r1c1 = SetButton(0, 0);
Button r1c2 = SetButton(0, 1);
Button r1c3 = SetButton(0, 2);
Button r2c1 = SetButton(1, 0);
Button r2c2 = SetButton(1, 1);
Button r2c3 = SetButton(1, 2);
Button r3c1 = SetButton(2, 0);
Button r3c2 = SetButton(2, 1);
Button r3c3 = SetButton(2, 2);
```

Finally the codes you could check :

```
this.Padding = new Thickness(20);
var deviceWidht = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
double buttonWidthandHeight = deviceWidht / 9;
int buttonCornerRadius = Convert.ToInt32(deviceWidht / 20);

Grid panel1 = new Grid();
panel1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
panel1.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
panel1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });


Button r1c1 = SetButton(0, 0);
Button r1c2 = SetButton(0, 1);
Button r1c3 = SetButton(0, 2);
Button r2c1 = SetButton(1, 0);
Button r2c2 = SetButton(1, 1);
Button r2c3 = SetButton(1, 2);
Button r3c1 = SetButton(2, 0);
Button r3c2 = SetButton(2, 1);
Button r3c3 = SetButton(2, 2);

Button SetButton(int row, int column)
   {
      Button createdButton = CreateButton(row, column);
      Grid.SetRow(createdButton, row);
      Grid.SetColumn(createdButton, column);
      panel1.Children.Add(createdButton);
      return createdButton;

   }
 Button CreateButton(int row, int column)
   {
      return new Button
       {
          Text = "Row " + row + " Column " + column,
          WidthRequest = buttonWidthandHeight,
          HeightRequest = buttonWidthandHeight,
          CornerRadius = buttonCornerRadius
          };
       }

    this.Content = panel1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, why should I start from 0 instead of 1? Is the same thing that happens with arrays, that the first element is 0? If so, why was the code working when I started from 1?

Comment: @JoãoGabriel Yes,if's the same as arrays,if you start from 1,it will work also,but the position will be different.